# Can a latent variable be depdendent on another latent variables in Structural Equation Modelling?

Tags: r, structural-equation-modeling, latent-variable, confirmatory-factor, lavaan

I am not an expert in research and statistics, but I am reading several research papers and I see that researchers, when using Structural Equation Modelling, use latent variables that are dependent on other latent variables, which are dependent on manifest variables. While this makes sense in theory, I don't see in practice how this can be logical and make sense. Any inputs on the subject?

Comment: Structual equation modeling is an entire can of worms unto itself. You may want to read an introductory text to supplement your understanding.

Comment: You mention you don't see how it can be logical to have paths between latent variables in practice. Is there an invalid argument or a contraction with the conclusion of an argument you've found?

Comment: Latents aren't usually dependent on manifest variables, manifest variables are dependent on latents. But yes. Exam grades (latent) depends on socieoconomic status (also latent).